# How to get print out a document in Java with customized page size. (SE)

Tags: java, swing, graphics, printing, size

How to get print out a document (Which taken from data base or current fields form the form) in java with customized page size. Mostly important thing is I want to customize the page as my requirements (May be text alignment also needed). am Not a java hard coder. Your helps will me big help to me.
Thanks.

Comment: this should help http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-10-2000/jw-1020-print.html

Answer (score 1):

not clear what is `(Which taken from data base or current fields form the form)` , I suggest to go throught the [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html) tutorial, there is detailed described [Printing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/index.html) in Java

Comment: I mean the printing date is getting from there. Sorry for that.

Comment: @ArMEd are you meaning print out and formatting value from java.util.Date or Calendar ???

Comment: no thats not necessary.  I just want to get print out. I just want to know how to set values to my printing page and customize the page size.

Comment: really I'm out of context, for sooner help better please to post the code in the http://sscce.org/ form

Answer (score 0):

Everywhere I've worked that wanted well formatted output from a Java back-end we've deployed Apache FO (http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/) which allowed us to use XSLT to convert XML to PDF.  It works really well, but has a pretty steep learning curve.

Comment: Can you please explain me how is this works? Will my requirements full fill from this?

Comment: The best overview is right on ApacheFOP's index page:  http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/.  "Apache FOP (Formatting Objects Processor) is a print formatter driven by XSL formatting objects (XSL-FO) and an output independent formatter. It is a Java application that reads a formatting object (FO) tree and renders the resulting pages to a specified output."

Comment: What I meant to say...The best overview is right on ApacheFOP's index page:  http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/.  I recommend that you spend some time there.  The basics are that you serialize whatever object graph you want to display into an XML Document with Java and then pass that Document into the FO processor along with an XSLT sheet that defines the formatting you want applied.  The XSLT sheet is where you put your page layout specifications (width, height, margins, background images, formatting stuff).